# how to update mongodb document when a button is clicked in html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, mongoose

im new to backend development.

i have been trying to make a CRUD notes application without using react,ejs etc.

the problem i face now is i am unable to edit document.

what its supposed to do is when edit is clicked on the html page of a document it should redirect to a page where you can edit the note and save it

this is the code i have got after using different methods

this is the express
[image: express segment]

this is the helper function to generate html
[image: helper function]

how do i make it to work

i have implemented the delete functionality similarly

express part

[image: express segment]

here is the helper function
[image: helper function]

i have tried various solutions but each of them use a different approach and i end up even more confused. how do i go about this what is the most optimum approach?

Comment: there was an error in the form action and in a couple other places, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to await for the helper function to finish, or else it will send back a promise/empty data.

Do this
`const html = await generateHTMLForUpdatePage(ele);`
instead of
`const html = generateHTMLForUpdatePage(ele);`

Comment: eventually did it in another method, but went back and tried this, it works